# Should I edit in tags for the right topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655236/rfc-regular-expression-operators/33655360) earlier where the OP assumed that the syntax being presented was Regular Expressions, so tagged the question with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex).

The answer is that it's not regular expressions at all, but ABNF, for which we have an [abnf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abnf) tag.

Should I remove [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) and add [abnf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abnf)?  Or just add [abnf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abnf)?  Or neither?

I feel other people may find the question because it *is* tagged [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), even though it's not actually about that.

Comment: @Matt I'm not really talking about exposure due to followers of the tag, more about whether having the [regex] tag on it will help others find it through organic search etc, if they have the same assumptions as the OP

Comment: I misunderstood then. I still think the _tag_ should go. If "regex" is still part of the title and question body then search engines can still find it if someone else makes that mistake. Only hurts people trying to search that with that tag on SO.

Comment: @Matt Right, that makes sense

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no reason to have the *tag* regex in the question. I understand how it ended up there in the first place but with what we know now it has no context.

It is true that the OP made that assumption incorrectly and that others might as well but that is not justification to keep that tag. However we could leave the title and body of the question alone (assuming no other issues).

That way crawling engines can still allow for people to make those searches using a regex keyword. I would expect those that were misguided are not likely to use [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) in their search. It is not a stretch that more people come in from Google anyway.

Also [abnf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abnf) should be added regardless if [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) is there or not.

Comment: Thanks - now edited.  Should have done it sooner - still a long way off the [Illuminator](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator) badge :)